# Using FiddlerCap for a HTTPS connection and the sessions are not being captured.

Tags: fiddler

1. Run FiddlerCap
2. Check Decrypt HTTPS traffic
3. Click OK for the dialog warning
4. Start/Stop/Save Capture

View in fiddler and am only seeing the CONNECT requests.

Any ideas? I've not had this issue before - now experiencing it on two separate pc's (Windows 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FiddlerCap was briefly bundled with an outdated version of `makecert.exe` (39kb) that caused this problem. I've fixed it for FiddlerCap v2.4.9.7 by updating makecert.exe to the latest (55kb), but on Windows 7 with the older build, you may be able to workaround this by simply deleting `makecert.exe` from the application's installation folder.